# How can I get two xbox360 consoles to have open NAT type using the same router?

Tags: xbox-360

I've been having this problem where either me or my sister's NAT type is strict. We can't join in a party together because of it and I have no idea how to fix this. My router model is 3801HGV and it does not have any UPNP settings for it. So how would I make it so both of us can have open NAT type?

Comment: This is kind of in border of the two sites' on-topicness, but you may want to try http://superuser.com/

Comment: @DJPirtu Agreed, it's more of a networking issue rather than an Xbox issue. Essentially, you'll need to open ports on your router that are specific to what the Xbox uses. uPNP has nothing to do with it.

Comment: This could be considered a general networking issue, but as a gamer who's been playing one Xbox or another for more than a decade, this is something I've had to deal with multiple times. Seems like it makes sense as a gaming expertise topic. Wouldn't hurt to ask it on both stacks for different perspectives on the problem.

Comment: Noticed a possible duplicate after posting an answer: [How can I get two Xbox 360's to be in “open nat” mode behind the same router?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/97586/108003)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, port forwarding issues on the 360 are solved by forwarding ports to a specific IP address. I can tell you from prior research on this topic that you can't forward ports to multiple IP addresses with one router.

The easiest thing to do would be to forward the appropriate ports to one box, and then put the other box in the DMZ. The DMZ puts the box outside the firewall, which is a security risk. That being said, I've had a 360 in the DMZ for years at a time without any issues. This is the current setup I'm using with my Xbox 360 in the DMZ, and my Xbox One with forwarded ports.

Another possible approach would be to get a 2nd router, forward the ports to that router, and put both boxes on the 2nd router. I haven't been able to get this to work myself, but I'm told it should be possible. This would be more secure, if you can get it to work.